# adding icons to a input button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to add a icon to a Button but it is not adding up for some reason.

```
 <input type="button" id="template" runat="server" value="Template" class="addTemplate" />
```

This is an asp page and due to some limitation we are not able to use the HTML 4 Button tag

Script

```
$(".addTemplate").button({
    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-plusthick" }
});
```

Is there a reason it is not showing up on the button?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it will not work on inputs: [jQuery Button Overview](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#overview)

From jQuery UI Page:
"When using an input of type button, submit or reset, support is limited to plain text labels with no icons."